# My boss is motivated but is no longer engaged and suspects he is losing his job and this is making everyone feel unhappy, what can I do?

Tags: management, work-environment, performance, motivation

My boss is very clever and is highly motivated, often putting in more time than he needs.

However, recently a number of people left the company, and everything seems to have came to a halt.

My boss has started swearing, nit picking about what people are doing, and saying things like `I couldn't care less I am sick of it quite frankly and would happily tell half the office to **** off tomorrow if it came down to it.`

He recently told me he thought he was going to lose his job when he was asked to attend the head office.

My boss has started saying things like he feels he doesn't have the authority to make decisions, yet he used to make them all the time.

When I want to do something for me or my team, he no longer backs me up and is basically saying no to everything.

He is not coming up with solutions to anything anymore and is simply pointing out where things have not been done correctly, as opposed to saying what could be done to put things right.

A massive investment was made in some technology recently, and it turned out to be a bad investment.

Now the mood has soured in the office and everyone is feeling unhappy.

There are times where I feel so sad about the situation I feel like applying for another role. However, I have worked at this company for many years now and I was always well looked after so don't want to throw in the towel just yet.

I was considering bypassing my boss but he has a lot of control and influence in the company, so I feel without concrete evidence it would be my word against his and I think others fear speaking out about the way he is being.

I like my boss, and think he is under a lot of pressure and would happily do anything to support him, but he is starting to make me feel like my job is pointless and that everything we do is a waste of time.

I have no idea where to turn or what to do anymore and feel isolated and trapped in a situation I can't do anything about.

So I am wondering if there any suggestions on what I can do to improve the situation.

Comment: Do you know of something that's changed / emerged recently in your company (other than the big investment in technology that didn't work out) that would coincide with this change in your boss's demeanour? People don't just suddenly change for no reason. I think it's either something has changed within the company, or could be something going on in the boss's personal life that they are struggling with.

Comment: ... for example, did a load of people just leave or is there some overarching reason? He thought he was going to lose his job at the head office meeting, why? Because of his recent attitude or because of other changes going on in the company, like other people being laid off / fired?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a battle that is being fought way above your paygrade.

The only thing you can really do is talk to your boss in private, preferably after work, offsite.

Remember, what you are seeing are the results of disputes you have not seen.

Maintain your course, and try to bring as much of a positive attitude as you can muster, make changes where you can, and update your resume.  If your boss has become bitter enough to start going "scorched earth", you may need to move on, be ready to do so.

Answer (score 5):

> My boss is motivated but is no longer engaged and suspects he is
>   losing his job and this is making everyone feel unhappy, what can I
>   do?

**Do your job**, to the best of your ability.  Part of your job is to help your boss do his by providing *any work related information* (ie *Systems is running slow due to XYZ and I fixed it before it was noticed* ).  Factual data is his best ally here, rumors are not.

Continue trying to help him as best you can.  Continue with your suggestions to improve the team's situation.  You cannot make your boss **do** anything however.

If the powers that be want your boss gone, *you don't have the influence to fix that*.  Just don't put yourself in the line of fire while this get's sorted out.

**Short answer**:  Do your job as best you can, help your boss where you can.

Answer (score 2):

Your boss is feeling bitter and burned.  This is apparently the core of your current issue.  So, try to help that as best you can.  The first thing you can do is go to your boss, and ask what you can do to help.  It's a nontrivial emotional lift, but talking with him, listening to him, and being supportive will likely help at least some, and it's highly likely make him more favorably disposed to you personally.  You might also get a better idea of what's going on for yourself, and perhaps some useful things you can do to help things work out a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers already. There is one other thing to contemplate in these sorts of situations.

Your boss is slowly digging a hole. He may soon just leave, quite possibly he is actively job hunting.

There is potentially an opportunity if the scenario is right for advancement. So look closely at what could be done to make yourself look like a good candidate for the job. Thinking all the angles through gives you an edge in a career, sometimes chances pop up briefly, you need to be prepared to roll any eventuality to your advantage at short notice.